# SQLite query for values in multiple fields

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to SQL in a SQLite database to select one record that contains a specific date string, time string, name string.  I am using PHP PDO:

```
$Qry = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Log WHERE QsoDate = '%s' AND TimeOn = '%s' AND Call = '%s'", $DTG["Date"], $DTG["Time"], $Call));
$qry = $SQLite->prepare($Qry);
$res = $qry->execute();
$tt = $qry->rowCount();
$Srow = $qry->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC);
```

$tt gets set to zero and $Srow gets set to false.  Both $qry and $res get set to a valid value. The combination of values should insure only one record is returned, and in testing I know the record exists, yet none of my query attempts seem to find it.  I suspect that my SQL syntax is wrong.

Comment: Echo the `SELECT` statement to see what is being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php): PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement. It is not applicable to `SELECT` statements.

Comment: But I am using the PDO library, not the SQLite3 library.  The manual suggests what I have.  Using $res failed.  See PDO  documentation at:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Corrected my answer after you specified using PDO.